# how to map timezone country with its cities in java

Tags: java, timezone, backend

I want to create a service which returns me timezone in this way:
List of timezones:

```
(UTC+01:00) Europe/Warsaw"
[{utc= (UTC+01:00)  Europe/Berlin, country= germany},
{utc= UTC+01:00) Europe/Warsaw , country= polnd},]
```

... And so on

Is it possible? because i did not find any example of something like this.

Comment: All you can do in Native Java is to get `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds().forEach(System.out::println);` this will return *a modifiable copy of the set of zone IDs*, but the countries it doesn't exist directly in Java, you need to pass by other APIs I guess

Comment: yes i was also wondering how does this made in grafana , i dont know exactly how to get countries https://play.grafana.org/d/000000012/grafana-play-home?orgId=1

Comment: Does this related with your question ?

Comment: i was inspired with example of grafana

Comment: What sense does it make? Europe/Berlin and Europe/Warsaw are not the same time zone even though these years they share an offset of +01:00 in winter. Maybe if you can explain why you want it, we can guide you better.

Comment: f Grafana can do that, my guess is they have built up their own time zone database. They may also be drawing on some Microsoft database, that I don’t know.

Answer (score 0):

### java.time can give you an approximation

```
    ZoneId inputZone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Warsaw");
    
    ZoneRules rules = inputZone.getRules();
    Instant timeNow = Instant.now();
    ZoneOffset currentOffset = rules.getOffset(timeNow);
    ZoneOffsetTransition lastTransition = rules.previousTransition(timeNow);
    ZoneOffsetTransition nextTransition = rules.nextTransition(timeNow);
    for (String zid : ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()) {
        ZoneRules zidRules = ZoneId.of(zid).getRules();
        if (zidRules.getOffset(timeNow).equals(currentOffset)
                && Objects.equals(zidRules.previousTransition(timeNow), lastTransition)
                && Objects.equals(zidRules.nextTransition(timeNow), nextTransition)) {
            System.out.println(zid);
        }
    }
```

Output from this snippet is:

> ```
> Europe/Brussels
> Europe/Warsaw
> CET
> Europe/Luxembourg
> Europe/Malta
> Europe/Busingen
> Europe/Skopje
> Europe/Sarajevo
> Europe/Rome
> Europe/Zurich
> Europe/Gibraltar
> Europe/Vaduz
> Europe/Ljubljana
> Europe/Berlin
> Europe/Stockholm
> Europe/Budapest
> Europe/Zagreb
> Europe/Paris
> Africa/Ceuta
> Europe/Prague
> Europe/Copenhagen
> Europe/Vienna
> Europe/Tirane
> MET
> Europe/Amsterdam
> Europe/San_Marino
> Poland
> Europe/Andorra
> Europe/Oslo
> Europe/Podgorica
> Atlantic/Jan_Mayen
> Europe/Madrid
> Europe/Belgrade
> Europe/Bratislava
> Arctic/Longyearbyen
> Europe/Vatican
> Europe/Monaco
> ```

Note that some of the zone IDs in the output are deprecated and/or aliases for other IDs in the output.

I am assuming that if a time zone has all of the following three, then it’s similar enough to be output.

1. The same current UTC offset (in this case +01:00)
2. The same last transition (in this case from +02:00 to +01:00 at 2020-10-25T03:00+02:00)
3. The same next transition (in this case to +02:00 at 2021-03-28T02:00+01:00)

Java doesn’t know the country of each time zone. You may look them up in the second link below.

### They are still different time zones

There are reasons why different time zone IDs are used. One of the most common reasons is that they in fact identify time zones that don’t always have the same time. To take the two time zones from your question as an example, Europe/Berlin and Europe/Warsaw, a few of the differences are:

- Warsaw introduced summer time (DST) from 1977. Berlin did not until 1980.
- Before World War I, Berlin was at offset +01:00 while Warsaw was as +01:24.
- Up to 1893 Berlin was at offset +00:53:28 all year, more than half an hour behind Warsaw.
- No one knows what the future will bring for each of those two time zones.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)
- [Time Changes in Berlin Over the Years](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/germany/berlin)
- [Time Changes in Warsaw Over the Years](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/poland/warsaw)